# Symfony2 - How to inject an optional parameter

Tags: php, symfony

Let's say I have a forum service. This service needs an URL to the forum API. What I want is that URL to be either internal or external.

If ***internal***, it would be a **route**, configured in routing.yml and returned by the router service.

If ***external***, it would be a **parameter**, configured in parameters.yml.

The approach I've thought of is:

*Look for the variable forum_url in parameters.yml. If it doesn't exist, try to obtain that route. Else, throw Exception.*

```
services:
    forums:
        class: Acme\ForumsBundle\ForumService
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager","@router", "%forum_url%"]
```

The problem with this implementation is that, if the variable is not defined, it throws an exception so what I would need is **to define it as an optional parameter** (like you can do with services (**"@?service"**).

What would be EVEN COOLER would be to be able to define something like:

```
"%forum_url% ? %forum_url% : @router"
```

Any ideas on how to achieve any of this?

PS: If there is another "better practice" approach, I'm open to inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in several ways.

1. Make `%forum_url%` not an optional but obligatory parameter but when you intend to have **internal** url just set `null` value (`~` in yml) to `%forum_url%` parameter. Then, inject both `%forum_url%` and `@router` into your service and check if `%forum_url%`: if it is not null use it, if it is null use **route**
2. Nicer way would be create another service, let's call it `url_resolver`. You inject this new service into your `ForumService`. Inside `url_resolver` service you do what is described in point 1, so you need obligatory `%forum_url%` and `@router` injected. This is just more SOLID way than option 1
3. Inject whole container into ForumService and check if `%forum_url%` is set. However, note that injecting whole container into service is considered as a bad practice

Comment: (responding to solution 1) Yeah, that's mi current implementation. I inject both and I check if forum_url == null. But I was hoping for something... better? 

Thanks for your input, though. It means my current solution is not that bad, is it?

Comment: check my edit and point 2. This is cleaner way of your solution and I guess it's clean enough (single responsibility is in place)

Comment: (**responding to solution 3**) I know 3 is bad practice. My brain itches if I try to inject the whole container, and it appears that's something good. xD

(**responding to solution 2**) I like that approach. I really like it. It's cleaner, even though it doesn't solve the need of having that parameter mandatory set on parameters.yml. I guess it's not that bad, though. That way the user knows where to "put it", if he decides to go external.

Thank you very mach for you comprehensive answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If your symfony version supports expression language than you can do it this way: 
"@=container.hasParameter('forum_url') ? parameter('forum_url') : service('router')"
http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/expression_language.html